# How to use QPainter with OpenGL 3.3 format?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm trying to use QPainter in my QOpenGLWidget. But it only works with 3.0 OpenGL version. What is the problem?

Here is my code.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "window.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QSurfaceFormat format;

  format.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);
  format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
  format.setVersion(3,3);

  // Set widget up
   Window *widget = new Window;
   widget->setFormat(format);

  // Set the window up
  QMainWindow window;
  window.setCentralWidget(widget);
  window.resize(QSize(800, 600));
  window.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

If i'll comment "format.setVersion(3,3);" everything will work fine. But my shaders won't start up.

And QOpenGLWidget subclass

```
#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H

#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>

class QOpenGLShaderProgram;

class Window : public QOpenGLWidget,
               protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
  Q_OBJECT

// OpenGL Events
public:

  void initializeGL();
  void resizeGL(int width, int height);
  void paintGL();

};

#endif // WINDOW_H
```

and simpliest example.

```
#include "window.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include "vertex.h"
#include <QPainter>


void Window::initializeGL()
{}

void Window::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{}

void Window::paintGL()
{
      QPainter p(this);
      p.setPen(Qt::red);
      p.drawLine(rect().topLeft(), rect().bottomRight());
}
```

Comment: What hardware and drivers do you have? Do they support OpenGL 3.3?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Basically, QPainter is designed to work with OpenGL ES 2.0. The 3.3 Core desktop OpenGL profile is not compatible with ES 2.0. If you use the 3.3 core OpenGL profile then you cannot use QPainter with it (at least not on OS X).

The issue is however apparently being worked on (https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/166202/). So perhaps next release this will be possible.

Currently, the way to get around this is to use QPainter to draw to a QImage and then draw that image as a texture in OGL.

Here is a proof of concept I just put together. *In production code* don't do this. Setup a shader + VAO (with VBO attached) for a quad. Then use glDrawArrays with an appropriate transform to put the texture on screen.

```
    glClearColor(1.f,1.f,1.f,1.f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Use QPainter to draw to a QImage and then display the QImage

    QFont f{"Helvetica",18};
    QStaticText txt{msg};
    txt.prepare({},f);
    auto dims = txt.size().toSize();

    QImage buffer(dims,QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    {
        QPainter p(&buffer);
        p.fillRect(QRect{{0,0},dims},QColor::fromRgb(255,255,255));
        p.setPen(QColor::fromRgb(0,0,0));
        p.setFont(f);
        p.drawStaticText(0,0,txt);
    }

    // Blit texture to screen
    // If you at all care about performance, don't do this!
    // Create the texture once, store it and draw a quad on screen.
    QOpenGLTexture texture(buffer,QOpenGLTexture::DontGenerateMipMaps);

    GLuint fbo;
    glGenFramebuffers(1,&fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER,fbo);

    texture.bind();
    glFramebufferTexture2D(
        GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER,
        GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        texture.textureId(),
        0);

    glBlitFramebuffer(
        0,
        dims.height(),
        dims.width(),
        0,
        width() / 2 - dims.width() / 2,
        height() / 2 - dims.height() / 2,
        width() / 2 + dims.width() / 2,
        height() / 2 + dims.height() / 2,
        GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT,
        GL_LINEAR);

    glDeleteFramebuffers(1,&fbo);
```